# Confusion with the $\lambda$ in this experiment

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, lift

I am still having trouble seeing why on this manual for experiment ideas, that they say the $\lambda$ is constant. My question is, how do we find this value of lambda or why can it be kept constant? If so what would be the constant value?

I will appreciate the clarification. 
[image]

Comment: I think this is engineering and should be addressed there https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is presumably explained in the article at the *Physics Teacher* linked at the end of the quote - and that link has been lost in the screenshot.

Comment: [Rotor (induced) inflow ratio](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19900006566.pdf) and the [Physics Teacher article](http://seniorphysics.com/physics/helicopterEEI.pdf).

Comment: It is certainly not about engineering. The context is a home-experiment, but the question is about the meaning of a parameter is an expression for the rotor-wing lift. Which means it is not even really a [experimental-physics] question, but instead a [fluid-dynamics] one. On the experimental side, the set-up displayed in the image is problematic insofar as the results will be affected by a non-trivial ground-effect. Attaching the drone to a latticework attached to the scale would yield slightly better results.

Comment: @dmckee also, the rotor downwash hits the plate, and it's not at all obvious to me what the effects of that will be.